# How to check and print if box is in a other div?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, canvas, dropdown

i need this for school project.
I create page where i can upload images, but it does not matter.
On this image i can create canvas, when i create first canvas this `id = room[1]`, when i create secound this `id = room[2]`
So i create 2 canvas and i have:

```
room[1]
room[2]
```

Okey, and i can drop on my image a icons, i write script to check if this icoin is in the canvas (room).
Now i need to do, if this icon is in canvas and i click a "print" button i need to see all my rooms and all what is in this room.

Look at the script:

```js
initDraw(document.getElementById('canvas'));

$( document ).ready(function() {
    sum = 0; 
 });       

function initDraw(canvas) {
    function setMousePosition(e) {
        var ev = e || window.event; //Moz || IE
        if (ev.pageX) { //Moz
            mouse.x = ev.pageX + window.pageXOffset;
            mouse.y = ev.pageY + window.pageYOffset;
        } else if (ev.clientX) { //IE
            mouse.x = ev.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
            mouse.y = ev.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
        }
    };

    var mouse = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        startX: 0,
        startY: 0
    };
    var element = null;

    canvas.onmousemove = function (e) {
        setMousePosition(e);
        if (element !== null) {
            element.style.width = Math.abs(mouse.x - mouse.startX) + 'px';
            element.style.height = Math.abs(mouse.y - mouse.startY) + 'px';
            element.style.left = (mouse.x - mouse.startX < 0) ? mouse.x + 'px' : mouse.startX + 'px';
            element.style.top = (mouse.y - mouse.startY < 0) ? mouse.y + 'px' : mouse.startY + 'px';
        }
    }

    canvas.onclick = function (e) {
        if (element !== null) {
            element = null;
            canvas.style.cursor = "default";
        } else {
            mouse.startX = mouse.x;
            mouse.startY = mouse.y;
            element = document.createElement('div');
            element.className = 'rectangle';
            sum = sum + 1;
            element.id = "room[" + sum + "]";
            $('.rectangle').attr('name', 'other_amount');
            element.style.left = mouse.x + 'px';
            element.style.top = mouse.y + 'px';
            canvas.appendChild(element)
            canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";
        }
    }
}

document.getElementById('removeall').onclick = function() {
$('.rectangle').remove();
sum = 0; 
}

document.getElementById('removeone').onclick = function() {
$('.rectangle').last().remove();
sum = sum - 1;
if(sum < 0){
 sum = 0;
}
}

  $( function() {
   $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ containment: "#containment-wrapper", scroll: false });
  } );


document.getElementById('checkposition').onclick = function() {

    var box = document.getElementById ("box");  
                var checkBox = box.getBoundingClientRect ();
                leftBox = checkBox.left;
                topBox = checkBox.top;
                rightBox = checkBox.right;
                bottomBox = checkBox.bottom;

                var room = document.getElementById ("room[1]");  
                var checkRoom = room.getBoundingClientRect ();
                leftRoom = checkRoom.left;
                topRoom = checkRoom.top;
                rightRoom = checkRoom.right;
                bottomRoom = checkRoom.bottom;

if(leftBox >= leftRoom && rightBox <= rightRoom && topBox >= topRoom && bottomBox <= bottomRoom){
alert('Box is in room');
} else {
alert('Box IS NOT in room');
}
}
```

```css
.rectangle {
    background: linear-gradient(60deg, rgb(171, 71, 188), rgb(142, 36, 170));
    opacity: 0.35;
    position: fixed;
}

#canvas {
 width:200px;
    height:100px;
    display: block;
}

#draggable {
 width: auto;
 display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,300|Material+Icons' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div id="canvas" class="snap" style="border: 2px solid red"></div>
<a id="removeall">Delete all rooms</a>
<a id="removeone">Delete last room</a>
 <a id="checkposition">Check if box is in room</a>
  <div id="draggable">
<i class="material-icons" id="box" style="font-size: 25px;">print</i>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Now i want new button "Done" and this button must print all items in rooms, and all rooms, example:

I have 2 rooms. room[2] and room[1]

When i click Done i must see

```
Room 1: Item Name
Room 2: Secound Item
```

Thanks for help :)